# Rails routes redirection for subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

We can't change the server configuration files, so we need to do our redirections at the rails level.

I have no problem with path redirections to external sites, like:

`match "/meow" => redirect("http://meow.com/")`

The issue is with the subdomains. I need to redirect for example:

http://my.example.com => http://example.com

How can this be done using routes.rb?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to @cfernandezlinux's [amazing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13716446/525478), here's the same in **Rails 4/Ruby 2** syntax:

```
constraints subdomain: "meow" do   
  get "/" => redirect { |params| "http://www.externalurl.com" }
end
```

- **`match`** in routes.rb is not allowed in Rails 4.0 anymore. You have to use explicitly `get`, `post`, etc.
- **hashrocket syntax** (=>) is for old Ruby, now in Ruby 2.0 we use param: 'value' syntax

Answer (score 4):

I ended up doing something like this:

```
constraints :subdomain => "meow" do   
  match "/" => redirect { |params| "http://www.externalurl.com" }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to hard-code the URL (so, for example, you can test/use this locally), you could do:

```
  constraints subdomain: 'subdomain_from' do
    get '/' => redirect(subdomain: :new_subdomain, path: '')
  end
```

So now `subdomain_from.google.com` will redirect to `new_subdomain.google.com`.